# delete session variable in php

Tags: php, ajax

i create a webpage in that i use session variables , when i click logout i clear the session variables using ajax , it working fine in IE , But when i use firefox sometimes the session is not destroyed , the code i used to clear session is [when i click logout button]

`function floadhomepage(){`

```
    ajaxFunction();
//alert('Logout clicked');
window.location.replace("index.php");
```

}

```
function ajaxFunction()
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }


else if (window.ActiveXObject){
// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
```

else {

```
  alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","logout.php",true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

in logout.php file contain the folowing code

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
unset($_Session['session variable name']);
?>
```

Please guide me to find the solution 
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
```

Comment: Tell us what happens. You logoff. Then how do you the session values are not destryed?

Answer (score 0):

`session_destroy()` alone is enough and is browser independent, as it happens on the server side.

Comment: ok , But still now the session variable is there when i use firefox . what can i do to destroy that session varable ?

Answer (score 0):

I had some sort of problem when

`$_Session['session variable name']` was an `array( 'first_element' => true, 'second_element' => '123456789' )`.

When I did

`unset( $_Session['session variable name'] )`

then

`session_destroy`, and `session_start` 
and redefined `$_Session['session variable name'] = array( 'first_element' => true );`

When I was var_dumping `$_Session['session variable name']`,

was `array( 'first_element' => true, 'second_element' => '123456789' )` with second_element!

I had to unset all elements in array.

This problem dissapeared when I upgraded php. Now I can't remember which php version I had.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever thought about browser caching? Even if you log out in firefox, firefox may still cache the logged in page.

try stopping page cache using something like this:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```